# AVCam preview covering navigation bar with iOS 15 and iPhone XR

Tags: swift, avcam

From iOS 12 to 14.8, my iPhone XR did not have any issue to display the AVCam output below the navigation bar.

Now, with the latest iOS 15.0.1, it overlaps the navigation bar.

Anyone has a clue why?

It seems to be ok with an iPhone 12.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was just a question of bad storyboard alignment. I was just lucky it was working before!